# pyAlsaaudio install on openSUSE

Tags: python-3.x, libalsa, pyalsaaudio

I'm trying to install pyAlsaaudio on my openSUSE distro

```
Output of uname -a: Linux linux-0cd5 4.12.14-lp150.12.48-default #1 SMP Tue Feb 12 14:01:48 UTC 2019 (268f014) x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I downloaded the source from this link,

http://larsimmisch.github.io/pyalsaaudio/pyalsaaudio.html

which includes a py setup file.

Initially I didn't have the gcc compiler installed, so I just installed it.

```
Snipped output of gcc -v: gcc version 7.3.1 20180323 [gcc-7-branch revision 258812] (SUSE Linux)
```

The setup.py file is still giving me issues, I think because I am missing the alsa/asoundlib.h file, similar to this thread:

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1586707

However, the solution there doesn't work for openSUSE, there isn't a libasound2-dev available for openSUSE.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I just found an answer for this here:

https://mailman.alsa-project.org/pipermail/alsa-devel/2013-December/069794.html

I used the following command:

```
sudo zypper install -C 'pkgconfig(alsa)'
```

which pointed me to a package I wasn't aware of - "alsa-devel". I wasn't able to find this package when I searched for things like "libasound"

Now I have the proper alsa/asoundlib.h file which is something that the creators of pyalsaaudio note could cause issues if it is absent.

setup.py compiles without issues now! Hope this helps someone else avoid losing 2 hours of googling!